# Access denied to folder even though Domain Admins have Full Control

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2016, access-control-list

I'm setting up a testing environment for permissions and I'm trying to understand what's going on here.

I have a Windows Server 2016 where my admin account used for testing is both a member of the local administrators group as well as the Domain Admins group. I have a folder where both the user, and the Domain Admins group, have Full Control. If I remove the user, but leave the Domain Admins with Full Control, I can no longer access the folder and get Access Denied both through windows explorer as well as Powershell (Get-ChildItem, Get-Acl, etc.)

Is there any logical reasoning for this happening? Shouldn't I be able to open/read/change the folder and its contents when Domain Admins has Full Control, and I am a member of Domain Admins? What am I missing here?

Comment: Is the powershell started with 'Run as administrator" so it is elevated?  Are you sure this isn't a UAC issue?

Comment: Run as admin was being used, I found some other blog post that I can't find now that mentioned UAC and that this is only an issue when trying to access it locally. I accessed the share from a different server and could access it so it was most likely that :) thanks for the help!